# explicitly release sweetalert popup after ajax call

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using sweetalert to ask user for an input to rename a tag. And then I make an ajax call to change the tag on server. If succeeded, I call a small callback function(postAction) which will update the UI and renamed the tag on UI. It works fine as long as little call back function has a statement "swal("done!");", so user clicks on this little confirmation message box, and sweetalert message box is released. I'm trying to see if there is a function I can call to release the input sweetalert pop up without the additional "swal("done")" statement, so user will have 1 less click. Is there an easy way to do this? 
All I can find now is to add a timer in the second pop up. swal("Done!", {timer: 500}); It's OK but not ideal.

```
renameTag = function(tagId)
{
    swal({
        title: "Rename Gallery Tag",
        text: 'Please provide a new tag name',
        content: "input",
        button: {
            text: "OK",
            closeModal: false,
        },
    })
    .then(name => {
        var tagName = name.trim();
        if (tagName.length == 0)
        {
            swal({
                title: "Rename Gallery Tag Failed",
                text: "Tag name cannot be empty",
                icon: "error",
                button: "OK",
            });
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ajaxAction("POST"
                    , "/User/RenameGalleryTag"
                    , { 'index': tagId, 'name': tagName }
                    , "rename gallery tag"
                    , {
                        'reload': false
                        , postAction: function () {
                            $(".selected-tag").text(tagName);
                            swal("done!");
                        }
                    });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `showConfirmButton: false` and not show the button confirmation or in the success function of the ajax call you can close the alert with `swal.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to close it like this

```
swal.close()
```